# Determine the state of a TCP socket

Tags: c++, api, tcp, network-programming

I'm starting to learn about how to implement in C++ a TCP server/client (on Windows and Linux).
At this moment, I'm implementing the server (and testing with the telnet as client).
The server application is sending and recieving data like a charm.. (I will implement the client after understand all the server side).
But I need to find a programmatic (C++ or O.S API) way to query the TCP socket state (ESTABLISHED, FIN_WAIT_2, CLOSE_WAIT, etc..) without use the write()/recv() to handle the error exception..

For example:

1. Server starts, bind the socket and wait a connection
2. A client starts and connect on the server
3. Here, I have a loop at the server that use the func "ioctlsocket(socket, FIONREAD, pbytes_available)" to determine when I have data to read..
4. If the client send some data, then "pbytes_available" will be > 1 and the server use recv() to get.
5. If the client doesn't sends anything, then the server can do other tasks and check if there are data on the socket at the next loop.
6. If I close the TELNET (client process) and run the "netstat", I'll see that the server socket is with the "CLOSE_WAIT" state, so I need to close the socket at the server side..

**And this is the question:** How can I query the TCP socket state to determine that I need close this session? (without use the send()/recv(), like the "netstat" do)

**Note:** I tried the "getsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &optval, &optlen )", but it return 0 when the state is ESTABLISHED/CLOSE_WAIT and the "optval" also doesn't changes.

Comment: You want to use select() to look for data to read and exceptions.  Note not all OS tell you when the other end of the socket process goes away.

Comment: What I want is get the state (exemple: CLOSE_WAIT), like the NETSTAT can do...

Comment: The usual BSD socket API does not expose that information.  Netstat must use some OS specific way to get the information.

Comment: You're confusing the state of the socket with the state of the port. The socket is either bound or not bound and connected or not connected. When it is connected it is also bound. Whether the connection is up or half-closed or closed is a completely separate matter.

Answer (score 1):

The usual technique with blocking-mode sockets is to dedicate a thread to reading the socket. When `recv()` returns 0 it means the peer has closed the connection and the *port* is now in `CLOSE_WAIT` state.

Alternatively you can use `select()` and friends to tell you when the socket is readable, which includes the case where `recv()` will return zero. Using `FIONREAD` as a polling mechanism is really pretty useless as it doesn't cover this case.