# When should a WSGI connection be closed?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, webserver, wsgi

I'm debugging a leak in a custom WSGI Server based on wsgiref.simple server, and we have found that we are not closing the connection properly, so the socket gets in the state CLOSE_WAIT. We are using a pool of threads.

This is the python library code that handle the request:

```
def handle(self):
    """Handle a single HTTP request"""

    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
    if len(self.raw_requestline) > 65536:
        self.requestline = ''
        self.request_version = ''
        self.command = ''
        self.send_error(414)
        return

    if not self.parse_request(): # An error code has been sent, just exit
        return

    handler = ServerHandler(
        self.rfile, self.wfile, self.get_stderr(), self.get_environ()
    )
    handler.request_handler = self      # backpointer for logging
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
```

Would be correct to override this method and close the socket if the lenght of self.raw_requestline is 0? ([Determine the state of a TCP socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081172/determine-the-state-of-a-tcp-socket))